# Azure Key Vault: Secret versions lifetime

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Im currently implementing a solution where we are going to store secrets once an hour. It will be the same secret that is updated, or rather we will call SetSecret, since UpdateSecret wont allow us to update the value of the secret. Since Seting a secret with an existing name creates a new version of the same, they will all have an expiry date.

The questions i got is as follows:

1. Are there any native retention logic for versions. Ex, removed after a certain time if expired/Removed when there is x amount of versions?
2. If not, is there any max count for versions?
3. Does it count towards some storage limit?

Manually deleting versions is not possible, so a possible solution will ofcource be to sometimes remove the secret. But this is a step i would like to skip since it will add more complexity if native retention of secrets is supported.

Cheers!

Comment: I did not find any official documentation about the retention limit.  The only thing I find is that there is a 90-days limit for soft-delete.

Comment: Yes exactly, i could not find anything about it, thats why i asked the question here. :)

Comment: By contacting the Azure support team, they confirm that there is no storage or amount limitation now. All versions will be kept. And if the amount is large, However, issues may occur if you try to backup/restore the secret (which includes all current versions). So, the proper recommendation is to keep the number of versions below 1000. You may need to take a purge operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no native retention logic within key vault and all the versions will remain in key vault.
2. There is no limit on the maximum number of versions of a particular secret.
3. No, it will not be counted towards any storage limit as well.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer, do you perhaps have any source for this, since i could not get an answer from the documentation (Maby im just bad at searching) Cheers!

Comment: I got this from the product team directly. It's not documented officially anywhere. Here is a blog (https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2019/03/27/maximum-number-of-objects-in-a-key-vault) by my colleague from Microsoft which talks about this.

Comment: According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-limits#limits-on-count-of-keys-secrets-and-certificates), if you have a lot of secret versions it can affect the performance of Key Vault backups.  Is there still no way to remove stale versions of secrets?